# $nin with $elemMatch doesn't work as expected

Tags: mongodb

I have the following bios collection from mongodb's site

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bios-example-collection/

Now suppose I need to find all the users who have won awards, but not in the years 2001 and 2011

I was trying to us $nin and $in but I am getting unexpected results

```
db.bios.count({awards: {$elemMatch:{ year:{ $nin:[2001,2011] } }}});
//returns 7 - not expected
```

and

```
db.bios.count({awards: {$elemMatch:{ year:{ $in:[2001,2011] } }}});
//returns  4 - expected
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current `$nin` query is counting the docs where at least one `awards` array element contains a year other than 2001 and 2011.

Use `$nin` without `$elemMatch` to match docs where none of the `$nin` array values appear in **any** element.

```javascript
db.bios.count({'awards.year': {$nin:[2001,2011]}});
```

But that will also include docs without *any* `awards` entries.  So to get a count of the docs with at least one award (i.e. users who have won awards), but none in 2001 or 2011 you need to `$and` in a qualifier that ensures `awards` has at least one element:

```javascript
db.bios.count({$and: [
    {'awards.year': {$nin:[2001,2011]}},
    {'awards.0': {$exists: true}}
]});
```